# Python textwrap.wrap break line without whitespace

Tags: python, string, word-wrap

I have

```
import textwrap
s = 'AG1   2470.1AUG   2470.1SEP   2466.4OCT   2459.3NOV   2446.8DEC   2431.1'
textwrap.wrap(s, width=61, break_long_words = True, replace_whitespace=False, drop_whitespace = False)

['AG1   2470.1AUG   2470.1SEP   2466.4OCT   2459.3NOV   ', '2446.8DEC   2431.1']
```

I want

```
['AG1   2470.1AUG   2470.1SEP   2466.4OCT   2459.3NOV   2446.8', 'DEC   2431.1']
```

I can't break the line when there isn't whitespace.

But this works,

```
s = 'aaaa'
textwrap.wrap(s, width=2, break_long_words = True, replace_whitespace=False, drop_whitespace = False)

['aa', 'aa']
```

Comment: When I understand you correctly, it is only acceptable to break between a number and a word and not just between any two characters, is that right?

Comment: Perhaps trying to wrap the string is the wrong approach, since it seems you want it interpreted as a sequence of 12-character substrings... Break it into the component bits, and recombine until just before you exceed your line length, instead... Or do the math to figure out where to break it - e.g. `[ string[:60], string[61:] ]`... Also, using `string` as a variable name is not a particularly spectacular idea...

Comment: @BurningKarl yes, but particularly I want to be able to use textwrap, not sure why it doesn't work.  There will always be a word following a number at the 80 character limit.

Comment: @twalberg Yes, I can do this, but I thought this was a cleaner approach and thought that this is what textwrap.wrap was for...  Point taken I just used string for the example.